# Redirect missing final slash

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

Here's my redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^somedir\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/mydomain\.com\/newdir\/somedir\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

When trying to reach

```
mydomain.com/somedir/Test.pdf
```

I am redirected to

```
www.mydomain.com/newdir/somedirTest.pdf (no slash before Test.pdf)
```

instead of

```
www.mydomain.com/newdir/somedir/Test.pdf (slash present)
```

What am I missing?

#### edit:

Here is my entire `.httaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^somedir/?(.*)$ "http://mydomain.com/newdir/somedir/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I have noticed that redirection works okay if I write

```
www.mydomain.com/somedir/Test.pdf
```

but redirects without a final slash with

```
mydomain.com/somedir/Test.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems right. Although I suggest you to change the `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^somedir/?(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/newdir/somedir/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
```

There is no need of the backslashes.

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried that as well, with the same result. .../somedir/other/ and /somedir/file.html get redirected okay, but path ending in .pdf does not.

Comment: @ipavlic what other rewriterules do you have?

Comment: I've edited my answer. It seems that redirection works okay if I prepend `www.`when trying to access my webpage.

Comment: @ipavlic what other rewrite rules do you have?

Comment: The one I wrote in the edit should be the only one as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ipavlic That alone should not cause any problems! anyways try the updated code.

Comment: I tested before trying to make proposed changes, and it seems to be working now. Quite confusing. I'll accept your answer with conditional `(www\.)` either way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ipavlic Welcome. The conditional `(www\.)` is just an optimization.